# Cannot install therubyracer -v '0.10.0' on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-mountain-lion, twitter-bootstrap-rails, therubyracer

I have no idea why this is not working. I had it working most of the day and then I suddenly can't run "bundle install" anymore.

I get:

```
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Installing therubyracer (0.10.0) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.0/.gitignore
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.10.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am on Mountain Lion (10.8.2) with ruby 1.9.3p194. Homebrew is updated. Gems are updated. XCode is up-to-date.

I have tried everythingcan't but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: it's look like permission problem but can't be sure where!

Answer (score 2):

this method work for me: 
 
specify the version to use in the gemfile of your application: 
  gem 'therubyracer', '=0.10', platforms: :ruby 
 
unistall libv8 & therubyracer in terminal, run next commands: 
gem unistall therubyracer 
 > select 3 to remove all versions 
 
gem uninstall libv8 
 
Select gem to uninstall: 
 1. libv8-3.3.10.4-x86-linux 
 2. libv8-3.11.8.3 
 3. All versions 
> 3 
 
then finally run bundle install & update

Answer (score 1):

Strange error, it has not rights to read the /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.0/.gitignore.

Have you tried to change rights on your ruby gem folder ?

Comment: What's the best way to change the rights? What should I change them to?